# How do I spend my 6 XP in Changeling the Lost?

Tags: changeling-the-lost

I am new to Chronicles of Darkness, and I have been enjoying my 2 sessions with changeling the lost but now I have come to a dilemma. I have 6 xp to spend, but when I look at pg 77, I don't understand *how* to spend it. For example, how much xp cost to raise what?

I have been playing mage the awakening 2nd and it is very easy.

For example my Int is 1 to raise it to 2 is it 5 or 10 (new dots X5); Then to raise it to 3 would that be 10 or 15?

Comment: I cleaned up some of the grammar and tried to clarify your question; this site has a proven history of clear writing producing more/better answers. Please check my changes (especially around the end of the first paragraph) and ensure I've kept the intent of your question the same.

Comment: This is a fairly solid first question, but it's still a great idea to take the RPG stack exchange [Tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour); it only takes a few minutes and has a lot of good information about how the site works and what's expected of users- both askers and answerers. For instance, this might be improved by bringing the title and body more in line with each other, so you get an appropriately broad or specific answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CoD experience cost is always **[NEW DOT] x [MULTIPLIER]** so if you have Int 1, cost is 2 x 5 = 10.